# wxFormBuilder with Python: access FlexGridSizer from subclass

Tags: python, class, inheritance, wxwidgets, wxformbuilder

I'm building a GUI in wxFormBuilder and writing the code for it in Python.

I've noticed that all the widgets I've built are assigned to `self` in the generated code.  For example, a GUI with a single piece of text might look like:

```
class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.myStaticText = wx.StaticText(self,wx.ID_ANY,'My Text',0)
```

So the object `myStaticText` becomes an attribute of the `MyFrame` class.  This is good, because I can write a new class that inherits this one and then perform other functions, such as updating the `myStaticText` object:

```
import MyFrmae
class GUI(MyFrame):
    def __init_(self,parent):
        MyFrame.__init__(self,parent)

    def updateText(self):
        self.staticText.SetLabel('My Other Text')
```

The problem is wxFormBuilder does not append a `self` in front of any FlexGridSizer objects.  So the generated code looks like:

```
myFlexGridSizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(3,1,0,0)
```

instead of:

```
self.myFlexGridSizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(3,1,0,0)
```

As a result, I cannot access that object from any other class, which I really need to do.

So...

1. Is there a way to access an object from another class if it doesn't have a `self` in front of it, even if I inherit it directly?
2. Is there a way to change a setting in wxFormBuilder so that it does append the `self`?

Comment: Just an advice: if you're class GUI's responsibility is just to update a MyFrame object, it should not inherit from MyFrame but have a MyFrame member and manipulate it this way(ie change the text, move stuff around...). That way you separate the view and the controller

Comment: Not a bad idea, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well you want to access the `FlexGridSizer` that the form builder has generated ?

I've never used the `wxFormBuilder` but I think the idea being is is that it creates a `wxFlexGridSizer`,manipulate it in order to do the layout of the form, and calls `SetSizer` on your `wxWindow` ( or `wxFrame` in your case )and forget about it because the layout is not going to change anymore.

One easy option (but it's not the best) is to call `GetSizer` on your frame and you can access a `wxSizer` from there.

The other option is to have a specific `sizer` member in your MyFrame where you would store the `wxFlexGridSizer`, but It would probably involve changing the code generated by the `wxFormBuilder`

Comment: Okay, I can look into that.  The reason I need to access the `wxFlexGridSizer` is because I want to add additional `wxStaticText` widgets to it when called by an external socket command, and as far as i know the only way to do that is through the `wxFlexGridSizer.Add()` method.  Any advice?

Comment: wxFormBuilder seems to be really good for quick prototyping, but not so much for details like this.  I think I'm just going to build up a initial draft, and from there on out just edit the source code manually to take care of the details and small changes.  I know enough wx that I'm comfortable with this.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: From my experience, adding stuff to sizers at run time can be complicated. Another option is for you to create the full widget including your additional fields. Then according to the situation you can hide the widgets you don't need (by calling `Hide()`).

Answer (score 0):

I tried simply calling the sizer `self.my_sizer` in wxFormBuilder 3.10.1 and the generated Python code is okay. I access the sizer like any other member of the generated class.